# Определить угол рыскания (yaw) используя только акселерометр

Tags: android

Подскажите, возможно ли вообще в принципе определить угол рыскания устройства (yaw, вращение относительно вертикальной оси) используя только акселерометр. Как это сделать используя магнетометр (компас) мне понятно.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Для этого вы должны быть уверены, что в устройстве есть два акселерометра в опорной плоскости xy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С одним акселерометром в нужной плоскости(xy) это можно сделать только если вы абсолютно точно знаете, вокруг какой точки вращается устройство. Если ось вращения неизвестна, то понадобятся дополнительные источники данных, например гироскоп.

[Вот статья на хабре](https://habrahabr.ru/post/137678/) как определять углы с помощью акселерометра и гироскопа.

**UPD** Для Roll и Pitch, в принципе, для покоящегося либо движущегося равномерно устройства, можно заложиться на ускорение свободного падения. Для Yaw этот фокус не пройдет.